# Python Time zone conversion confusion

Tags: python-3.x, timezone, pytz, python-dateutil

I have this simple function and test here:

```
def convert_to_current_time_zone(server_time, test_timezone = None):
  """
  Converts a time from server time to the users time zone, taking daylight savings
  time into account if relevant.
  Args:
    server_time: A string object representing server time via YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss format
  Returns:
    A datetime object in the time zone the user is currently in.
  """
  global server_time_zone

  server_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(server_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=server_time_zone)

  if test_timezone:
    converted_datetime = server_datetime.astimezone(tz = test_timezone)
  else:
    converted_datetime = server_datetime.astimezone(tz = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo)

  return converted_datetime
```

```
class TimezoneConversionTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_day_light_savings(self):
    # Input will be the last day of September 2023, 11:31am, PDT this should
    # convert to 4:01 am ACST (ACDT) which will trigger the DST, resulting in a
    # final time of 5:01am.
    server_time = '2023-09-30 11:31:00'
    global server_time_zone
    server_time_zone = dateutil.tz.gettz('America/Los_Angeles')
    converted_time = convert_to_current_time_zone(server_time, dateutil.tz.gettz('Australia/Darwin'))
    self.assertTrue(bool(converted_time.dst()))
    self.assertEqual(converted_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "2023-10-01 05:01:00")
```

When I run this code I get the time 4:01. Perhaps my math is wrong but the time difference between PDT and ACST is 16.5 hours, so when 11:31 is given 16 and a half hours from then is 4:01 am the next day, however since daylights saving should of been in effect from 2am onwards of the first Sunday of October (October 1st is a Sunday) this should of triggered daylight savings to now be in effect which according to (https://www.australia.gov.au/time-zones-and-daylight-saving) should of brought the clock forward an hour.

Can anyone explain the problem here? I thought maybe it has something to do with PDT already being in effect but I can't make sense of it. Perhaps the method of calling replace then as timezone does not work as I intend. Or maybe even I can't count and it should be 4:01am

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Australia and Los Angeles are on opposite sides of the international date line, did you account for that?

Comment: I believe that the time difference of the two time zones already incorporates the International Date Line. Correct me if that isn't the case though.

Comment: I should mention to anyone reading this code for a method to convert timezones from some server time (in their own timezone) to the user's local time zone this won't work using tz = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo in some cases.

This is because tzinfo does not give the IANA name for the timezone, instead sometimes returning a Time zone abbreviation ("Cen. Australia Standard Time" for example). This means it will not take Daylight Savings into account, or will apply Daylight savings when it's not in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Australia/Darwin' is a separate timezone to 'Australia/Adelaide'. While they share ACST only 'Australia/Adelaide' has daylight savings.

This fixes the test:

```
      def test_day_light_savings(self):
        # Input will be the last day of September 2023, 11:31am, PDT this should
        # convert to 4:01 am ACST (ACDT) which will trigger the DST, resulting in a
        # final time of 5:01am.
        server_time = '2023-09-30 11:31:00'
        global server_time_zone
        server_time_zone = dateutil.tz.gettz('America/Los_Angeles')
        converted_time = convert_to_current_time_zone(server_time, dateutil.tz.gettz('Australia/Adelaide'))
        self.assertTrue(bool(converted_time.dst()))
        self.assertEqual(converted_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "2023-10-01 05:01:00")
```

Comment: Wow, that was subtle.  Something I suspect only an Australian would know.